# Powershell to properly shut down a Sharepoint document

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powerpoint

I'm trying to use `PowerShell` to shut down a `PowerPoint` presentation located on a `SharePoint` site.

I've use bot the `process.kill` and the `Stop-Process` commands but the thing is that the file is not properly closed and is messed up on the `SharePoint` site. If I delete it, it comes back. I know that is related to short term lock but I want to avoid that. If I `AltF4` the `PowerPoint` presentation or `Esc` it, the file is left in a stable state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving and closing the `PowerPoint` Presentations down gracefully before you kill the processes with `Stop-Process`:

```
# If there is a powerpoint application running
If(Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "POWERPNT"}){

    $pp = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('powerpoint.application')
    $pp.Presentations | % { 
        $_.Save()
        $_.Close() 
    }

    # Kill off all PowerPoint apps
    Get-Process | ?{$_.ProcessName -eq "POWERPNT"} | Stop-Process
}
```

Comment: That was fast ! Seems to be working. I just get an error when Powerpoint is not started before lauching the ppsx but it closes properly with no lock. So that'll do it. Thanks !

Comment: @theclaw I have added in an `if` to my answer so that it will only run if there is `PowerPoint` process running. That might solve your issue? If my answer has answered your question could you accept it, thanks. :)

Comment: ah, by the way, it looks like I can't have 2 scripts running at the same time ? I've got another one that starts powerpoint with a specific presentation when an event occurs in the sharepoint folder. It's supposed to be also running in the background but does not. 

I've got one script to kill PPT when a new file is dumped in the folder and one to start PPT when a ppt file is renamed. But apparently only one can be running.

Comment: Have you tried using `Start-job` to run it in the background? e.g. `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { ... Your background Script .... }` Then continue on with the normal script.

Comment: Can I add that in the 1st script ? To me it looks like when Script1 invokes Script2 then Script1 ceases to run.

But Script1 and Script2 have to be running together to monitor the presentation folder on the sharepoint site. That's where I'm stuck so far :)

Comment: You could have one master script which kicks off both the scripts (1 & 2) as background jobs. Then you can wait on both jobs to finished using something like `While(Get-Job -State Running) {Sleep -s 5 }` or even kick them of again if they finish.

Comment: Well, I've started my 2 scripts with:

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {"C:\PS1\Script1"}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {"C:\PS1\Script2"}

They show as Completed when I type Get-Job.

But they don't grab they event they're supposed to, so nothing happens.

So, what did I miss ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to copy and paste the whole script into the -ScriptBlock { ... }  parameter not just give it the path.